# Spring Boot Exception details

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I am trying to log the exception in the spring boot based web service.

So I have used **GlobalExceptionHandler**
My code :

```
@ControllerAdvice  
@RestController  
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {  

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)  
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Ankit == "+e.getMessage());
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        System.out.println(errors.toString());
        return e.getMessage();
    }
 }
```

the code is working fine. What I want is exception details. I mean the code where the exception occurs? File name / line ? or do I have to parse the stacktrace? I mean spring boot must have thought something for this?

Comment: Afaik spring doesn't have anything to parse exceptions in order to find the line where exception occurs. The best bet would be to iterate through the stack trace, check package names and take the ones that you're interested in (line info will also be included there as well so you can form the message as you like).

Comment: You should use some logging framework to capture error logs instead of sysout statement. As far as tracing is concern you have to do it manually using stacktrace.

Answer (score -2):

**Using IDE**

If you are using any IDE then go to `Console Window`.

1. Clear console
2. Repeat action that causes Exception
3. Search in `Console` (CTRL + F) for `ERROR`
4. Look for line above(Look for 2-3 lines if you don't find immediate above) the line which contains `ERROR`. This line has details of Class, Method where Exception has occurred.

**Without looking at Console or Logs**

If you want to use it in production then, handling atleast known exceptions(like BAD_REQUEST, NOT_FOUND etc.) the way it is done below might be helpful *(adding an extra parameter to Exception Class)* :

```
Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployeeById(employeeId);
if (null == employee) {
logger.error("No tenant exists for employeeId:"+employeeId);
throw new ObjectNotFoundException("Emplyee Not Found",  this.getClass().getSimpleName();));
}
```

here `this.getClass().getSimpleName();` will be passed as parameter from `EmployeeController` class. So in `ObjectNotFoundException` we can add a parameter `ClassName` and When you handle it in `GlobalExceptionHandler`, you can do it as it is done below,

```
@ControllerAdvice  
@RestController  
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {  
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)  
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public String handleException(Exception e){

        System.out.println("Ankit == "+e.getMessage());
        StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
        String classWithExceptionName = e.getClassName(); 
        // you need to add this above getter method to your Exception Class
        System.out.println(errors.toString());
        return e.getMessage();
    }
 }
```

This is for known common exceptions. We need to add `extra parameter(ClassName)` to All Custom Exceptions that you are throwing and that might be little extra code but i think that is the way. Hope it helps now.

Comment: I need to use this in Production,

Comment: Ohh..you didn't mention that..then you will have to keep checks at controller side for any exceptions.. at least known exceptions.. otherwise then parsing stack trace will be the option..@Ankit my bad for wrong answer